# How can I log an event with indexed fields in Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, events, logs

As you can see below, the indexed field is ignored, and the last field is set to zero:

```
contract MyContract {
    event MyWorkingEvent(
        address thing4,
        address thing5,
        address thing6);

    event MyBrokenEvent(
        address indexed thing1,
        address thing2,
        address thing3);

    function logAllTheThings(){
        MyWorkingEvent(0x12, 0x34, 0x56); // works :)
        //output => MyWorkingEvent["0x12","0x34","0x56","0x78"]

        MyBrokenEvent(0x12, 0x34, 0x56); // doesnt work :( 
        //output  => MyBrokenEvent["0x34","0x56","0x78","0x0"]
    }
}
```

I'm testing all this from browser-solidity

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you're testing this? I tried copying your code into browser-solidity and got a bunch of errors saying events aren't supported at this time.

Comment: It works for me. You are probably on an older version. Let me know if it works for you here: https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in browser-solidity. I went ahead and deployed your contract using Mist and was able to trigger the events and see the values just fine.

[image: working events in Mist]

Comment: Thanks ryepdx. @zachferland found that is also works fine in truffle. I'll submit the issue to the browser-solidity people on github.